# KVM import/export process for movement between boxes

Tags: centos, redhat, kvm-virtualization

How can I export a KVM VM from one machine, and import it to another machine also running KVM?

The host to export from is running CentOS, and the import host is running Red Hat.

I've tried to find documentation on the matter but no luck.  My KVM knowledge is minimal, the machine was installed using the GUI virt-manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VIRT-V2V can automate the process, but you can simply copy the disk image to the same directory, and copy the VM definition xml file as well.

Comment: Sounds good.  I've now found the VM definition xlm in /etc/libvirt/qemu.  If I wanted to test the process by copying a VM on the same box would it suffice to just copy the disk and xml definition (renaming as appropriate) and then make up a new UUID?

Comment: yes it would. more so, you can keep the old uuid in the xml